# Why am I getting this CMAKE_C_COMPILER error when installing slycot?

Tags: python, cmake, pip

Good morning/evening,

I am trying to install slycot through pip install. Unfortunately I am getting the following error message.

I have already installed CMake.
Any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks

Building wheel for slycot (PEP 517) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\francescos\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\francescos\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\FRANCE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp96ecekd1'
cwd: C:\Users\FRANCESCOS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o1zu4kc_\slycot_1832234bc3214bdf8ec3b243db79b538
Complete output (56 lines):
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

```
  cl

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/FRANCESCOS/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-o1zu4kc_/slycot_1832234bc3214bdf8ec3b243db79b538/*cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/FRANCESCOS/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-o1zu4kc*/slycot_1832234bc3214bdf8ec3b243db79b538/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
FC ('-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=', 'c:/users/francescos/python38/Library/bin/flang.exe')
F2PY ('-DF2PY_EXECUTABLE=', 'c:/users/francescos/python38/Scripts/f2py.exe')
NUMPY_INCLUDE ('-DNumPy_INCLUDE_DIR=', 'c:/users/francescos/python38/Include')
['-DSLYCOT_VERSION:STRING=0.4.0', '-DGIT_REVISION:STRING=ac0944b363a6cfcc0c3d5128cdd484d74173aa3b', '-DISRELEASE:STRING=True', '-DFULL_VERSION=0.4.0.gitac0944b', '-GNMake Makefiles', '-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=c:/users/francescos/python38/Library/bin/flang.exe', '-DF2PY_EXECUTABLE=c:/users/francescos/python38/Scripts/f2py.exe', '-DNumPy_INCLUDE_DIR=c:/users/francescos/python38/Include', '-DCMAKE_Fortran_SIMULATE_VERSION=5.0.0', '-DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID=Flang', '-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON']

scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

Building windows wheels for Python 3.8 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

```
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/
```

---

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for slycot
Failed to build slycot
ERROR: Could not build wheels for slycot which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: If you have some version of Visual Studio Community installed, run CMake from a Visual Studio command prompt so the environment variables for the compiler are enabled,

Comment: I opened  a  VS command prompt and I got

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>cmake


Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
  cmake [options] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Run 'cmake --help' for more information.


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>

What do I need to type in the VS comman prompt?

Comment: " To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat)"
I have found the vcvarsall.bat. How do I run cmake from this?

" Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH." How do I do this?

Comment: ***How do I run cmake from this?*** Type cmake-gui or cmake from the cmd.exe instance launched using the "Visual Studio Command prompt" for whatever version of VS you are using. Assuming cmake was installed and modified the system PATH environment variable,

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks.
When I do this I get:
'''Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
  cmake [options] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Run 'cmake --help' for more information.'''

What do I need to do next?
THanks again